# Azure Functions deployment in VS code using conda environment

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have been having a little bit of inconsistency issue with python settings in VS code while trying to run my azure functions locally. I am trying to avoid using the "venv" environment that VS code automatically sets for an azure function project and instead use a pre-created conda environment I made and have all the requirement installed in.Just to clarify, this is about local deployment and not azure portal.

**myfunc__init__.py**:

```py
import json
import logging
import time

import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd                    # Import Error happens here!

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
   ...
```

**.vscode\Settings.json**:

```
{
  // Local Machine Conda VENV (Define CONDAPATH in Windows Environment)
  "python.condaPath": "%CONDAPATH%",
  "python.pythonPath": "%CONDAPATH%\\envs\\azure\\python.exe",
  "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "%CONDAPATH%\\envs\\azure",

  // Created Local VENV by VS Code (pythonPath is difference for MAC vs Windows)
  //"azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",

  // Azure Function Stuff
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
  "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "func: pack --build-native-deps",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
}
```

**Note:** If I replace the `%CONDAPATH%` with an actual absolute path to conda, the issue remains.

Just in case of need, `launch.json` is configured as bellow:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Linux_PyFunc",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

When VS Code runs the functions, the deployment completes without issues and the local links are generated. Once I call the function via `Postman`, the return is `HTTP 500` status which is due to not being able to `import pandas` with error module not found.

If I set `"azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv"` in `settings.json` the functions gets deployed locally and once triggered/called, it returns `HTTP 200` status and proper response.

So, this brings me to the question, if VS code supports conda environment for azure function deployment and if so, what am I missing here?

Comment: To be sure that I understand the issue correctly, are you saying this Conda with VS Code and Azure Functions works fine locally for you? But you get HTTP 500 when deployed to Azure?
Or does it not work locally as well?

Comment: It's about local deployment with my conda env. I am not having issues with azure portal since the python settings are taken care of.

Comment: Moe: were you able find answer ? i am facing exact issue. not able to guide "launch.json" file to  point to conda.

Comment: Rakesh, Things got a bit more complicated since we had some team members on Mac and some on windows. So, we had to make adjustments. See my current vscode posted as answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did to get conda environment instead of venv

Look in the settings.json file. Since I already had the python extension installed and I had already configured my interpreter for this project, I had a setting called `python.pythonPath`. I want to use this python instead of the venv so I comment out the venv setting.

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "./functions/",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    // "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "../.venv", // Ignore not going to use
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    ...
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\path\\to\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenviron\\python.exe",
   ...
}
```

Next edit the tasks.json. Notice there is a pipInstall task. I changed the widows command to use my `python.pythonPath` defined in settings.

The old value was something like `"command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install...` the new value is `"command": "${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip install...`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        ...
        {
            "label": "pipInstall",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip install -r ${config:azureFunctions.deploySubpath}/requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip install -r ${config:azureFunctions.deploySubpath}\\requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip install -r ${config:azureFunctions.deploySubpath}/requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing similar concerns, I have ended up with following setting thanks to answer provided by Brig:

### .vscode\settings.json

```json
{
    // python.pythonPath is machine-dependent, AVOIDING a set value here
    // Local Machine Conda VENV (Define CONDAPATH in Windows Environment)
    "python.condaPath": "${env:CONDAPATH}/Library/bin/conda.bat",
    "python.pythonPath": "${env:CONDAPATH}/envs/azure/python.exe",
    // Needs `pyvenv.cfg` present in venv path?
    // "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "${env:CONDAPATH}/envs/azure",

    // Created Local VENV by VS Code (pythonPath is difference for MAC vs Windows)
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",

    // Windows pythonPath
    // "python.pythonPath": "src/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
    // MAC pythonPath
    // "python.pythonPath": "src/.venv/bin/python",  
    
    // Azure Function Stuff
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "src",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
    "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "func: pack --build-native-deps",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",    
}
```

### .vscode\tasks.json

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pipInstall",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "pipInstall",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```